# PostgreSQL json search

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'am thinking about storing some data in postgres jsonb data type. There would be a structure like

```
{"name": "Jhon Smith", "emails": ["smith@test.com", "agent@matrix.net"],
 "phones": ["123456789", "987654321"]}.
```

I know, that i can search this structure like

```
where contact->'emails' @> '"smith@test.com"'::jsonb;
```

But what I need is to search my data with some LIKE operator, so

```
where contact->'emails' <SOME_JSON_LIKE_OPERATOR> "smith"';
```

I can't find if psql have something similar, maybe it does not. So, maybe I can convert contact->'emails' field to Text ('["smith@test.com", "agent@matrix.net"]') and then use simple LIKE.. How would you have solved this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expand the json array into a recordset of text and search that in whatever manner you like:

```
where exists (
    select 1 from json_array_elements_text(contact->'emails')
    where 
        value like "%smith%"
    )
```

Comment: @donkopotamis Awesome, thank you! That's exactly what i was looking for.